# Get sum of row where username is the current user's name

Tags: php, mysql

This code just displays a blank webpage.  Is there anything wrong with it?  It is supposed to show the total points the logged in user has.

```
<?php

session_start();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "randompassword";
$dbname = "transactions";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$query = "SELECT sum(points) AS points FROM transaction WHERE username =    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_SESSION['username'])."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

print($row)
?>
```

Comment: You have a table named `transaction`? If so, I'd highly recommend you change that.

Comment: `transaction` is reserve word and so escape it using backtique.

Comment: As a general rule, when PHP shows you a blank page it is because the PHP error reporting (http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) is set to hide it. Look at your logs for the specific PHP error encountered.

Comment: @Rahul `transaction` is a keyword, but it's not a reserved word. There's no `(R)` next to it on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: `print($row)` won't work, because `$row` is an array. Use `var_dump($row)`. But it shouldn't produce a blank page, it should print the word `Array`.

Comment: @Barmar, Ahh! right but either way should be escaped or not used as normal literal.

Comment: @Rahul You don't have to escape it if it's not reserved.

Comment: What happens if you run the query by hand in the mysql command line or phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Now it just displays NULL

Comment: array(1) { ["points"]=> NULL } is what the page displays, please help

Answer (score 0):

1. You should enable the error_reporting like this

   `error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set("display_errors", 1);`
2. `transaction` is a keyword in mysql. So use back tick ( ` ).
3. Instead of using direct substitution values, you could use below methods to avoid sql injection.

> Using MySQLi (for MySQL):
>
> ```
> $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = ?');
> $stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
>
> $stmt->execute();
>
> $result = $stmt->get_result();
> while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
>     // do something with $row
> }
> ```

Please refer [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)